# Average rate of change at an exact point

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I had this question in my precalculus text book:

> Water is draining from a large tank. After $t$ minutes there are $160,000-8000t+t^2$ gallons of water in the tank. Estimate the rate at which the water runs out after exactly $10$ minutes.

Now I used this difference quotient formula: $2t+h-8000$

At first I used $10$ for $h$ and $0$ for $t$, but it turned out to be the opposite. Why did we use $10$ for $t$ and $0$ for $h$? What would we have come out with if we used my original values? Thanks!

Comment: $h$ is nowhere in the problem.  We are asked about $t=10$, which is why we use $t=10$.  Although you tagged it precalculus, it appears you are supposed to take the derivative.  You did that fine except for the appearance of $h$

Comment: @RossMillikan So h is 0? Don't we want the rate of change after exactly 10 minutes(from t=0 to t=10)?

Comment: I still don't see where you are finding $h$.  The problem asks about the volume of water, not the height. As mzp says, you are asked for the instantaneous rate of change in the volume when $t=0$.  If you just take the difference in volume between $t=0$ and $t=10$, you get the average rate of change over those $10$ minutes.

Comment: h here is the difference between final and initial time. I thought he asked for **h=10**, since **t=0** untill **t=10**. But I turned out wrong, since he asked for t=10 and h=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rate of change is the derivative. So if

$$ f(t)=160,000-8000t+t^2$$

then

$$ f'(t)=-8000+2t$$

and, therefore

$$ f'(10)=-8000+2\cdot 10=-7980$$

which is the rate of change in minute $t=10$.

---

Without using derivatives, you could estimate the desired rate of change by calculating

\begin{align} \frac{f(10+h)-f(10)}{h} &= \frac{160,000-8000\cdot(10+h)+(10+h)^2 - (160,000-8000 \cdot 10+10^2)}{h} \\[2ex]
&= \frac{-8000h+20h+h^2}{h}
\end{align}

If $h=1$ this delivers

$$ \frac{f(10+h)-f(10)}{h} = -8000\cdot 1+20\cdot 1+1^2 = -7979$$

and the lower $|h|$ is the better the estimate. In the limit

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(10+h)-f(10)}{h} = f'(10).$$

Answer (score 0):

You use $t_0$ for $t$ and $h=10$.

$=\frac{\Delta D(t_0)}{\Delta t}=\frac{f(t_0+h)-f(t_0)}{h}$

$=\frac{160,000-8,000(t_0+h)+(t_0+h)^2-(160,000-8,000t+t_0^2)}{h}$

*Inserting 10 for h*

$=\frac{160,000-8,000(t_0+10)+(t_0+10)^2-(160,000-8,000t+t_0^2)}{10}$

$\frac{160,000-8,000t_0-80,000+t_0^2+20t_0+100-160,000+8000t-t_0^2}{10}$

$=\frac{-80,000+20t_0+100}{10}=-8000+2t_0+10=-7990+2t_0$

This is the difference between the volume at $t=t_0+10$ and the volume at $t_0$. Therefore you have to take the negative value to get a positive value:
$7990-2t_0 \ \  \forall \ t_0 \leq 3995$

This is the amount of water which drained from the tank on average in one minute, if you have a period of 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Q$ be the quantity of the water in gallon at any time $t$ then $$Q=160000-8000t+t^2$$ then the flow rate of water is equal to the time rate of change of volume $\frac{dQ}{dt}$ is given as $$\frac{dQ}{dt}=-8000+2t$$
Now, substituting $t=10\mathrm{min}$ the flow rate is given as $$\frac{dQ}{dt}=-8000+2(10)=-7980\ \mathrm{gallon/min}$$
**Note:** Negative sign indicates that the volume $Q$ is decreasing with the time $t$.

Comment: Where did you get the second equation from?

Comment: you can simply differentiate $160000-8000t+t^2$ w.r.t. $t$

Comment: I did not take derivatives yet :P